# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null [Chrome Extension]

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('item_save').onclick = function() {
    var item_name = document.getElementById('item_name').value;
    var item_size = document.getElementById('item_size').value;
    var item_type = document.getElementById('item_type').value;

    chrome.storage.sync.set({'itemName' : item_name}, function() {
        alert(itemName)
    });
}
}
```

Javascript (content.js) above^

```
        <div class="item_name_hold">
            <input type="text" class="item_name" name="item_name" placeholder="Item Name..." id="item_name">
        </div>

        <div class="item_size_hold">
            <input type="text" class="item_size" name="item_size" placeholder="Item Size..." id="item_size">
        </div>

        <div class="item_type_hold">
            <input type="text" class="item_type" name="item_type" placeholder="Item Type..." id="item_type">
        </div>

        <input type="button" class="item_save" name="submit" value="Save" id="item_save">
```

HTML above^

I also included the content.js file in the manifest.json file, and I have a script tag at the top of the popup.html file to include content.js as well.

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null" and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined" are my two errors.

Answer (score 0):

chrome.storage is only available on in web extension JS scope. The "sync" error looks like this is executed as content script (which is executed in parallel scope of the webpage).

Since you've mentioned popup.html I would suggest comparing the code to official popup example and make sure popup html is specified correctly in manifest.json: https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/beastify

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand now.
I removed some things and now I'm not getting errors, I'll try to sort out the chrome.storage thing, just trying to save variables locally to the extension.